# EE relationship field inside tagger entries loop

Tags: relationships, loop, devdemon-tagger

Try as I might (and it might not be possible I guess) I have a relationship field in EE of author against an article channel.

I want to show the author of an article while showing the article for a given tag.

```
{exp:tagger:entries channel="article" tag="{segment_2}" custom_fields="article_byline"}

{tagger:entry_title}

{tagger:article_byline}
    {tagger:article_byline:title}
{/tagger:article_byline}

{/exp:tagger:entries}
```

I do get entries returning - just no author though.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but take a look at wrapping a channel entries tag with the tagger entries tag pair: http://www.devdemon.com/forums/viewthread/2625/

Comment: Yeah we saw that but no joy. In fact, I was surprised at Brad's answer because entry_id would need to be tagger:entry_id